# Custom button - Java script error - missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a created a custom button using Onclick Javascript action.

I have a custom picklist field on Opportunity; I am just checking the value selected for this field on  click of this button.

If the value is X or Y or Z then it should stay in the same page with an alert message,else it should take them to a different site.

The below script works perfectly, but when I click this button on opportunities in which the opportunity name has double quotes then it throws the below error:

> missing ) after argument list

e.g: " N "Third Avenue (Opportunity name)

Can anyone please assist me in trouble shooting and a workaround..

**Javascript:**

```
function checktype() {
if("{!Opportunity.Opportunity_Type__c}" == "X" ||
"{!Opportunity.Opportunity_Type__c}" == "Y" ||
"{!Opportunity.Opportunity_Type__c}" == "Z"
 )
{
alert("Opportunity type: {!Opportunity.Opportunity_Type__c} is not supported ");

return;

}
else
{
window.location.replace("https://Anothersite.COM");
}

}
checktype();
```

Comment: The redirect url contains the opportunity name, i believe that is causing the issue:

window.location.replace("https://anothersite.com/login/connect.do?destination=application&SfdcOpId={!Opportunity.Id}&SfdcOpName={!Opportunity.Name}&SfdcServerURL={!API.Partner_Server_URL_280}&SfdcSessionID={!API.Session_ID}");

How do i overcome the double quotes character while dynamically passing the oppty name in the redirect url

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [URLENCODE](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#URLENCODE) function on the oppotunity name when generating the url so that it retains all those special characters properly

```
window.location.replace("anothersite.com/login/…
{!Opportunity.Id}&SfdcOpName={!URLENCODE(Opportunity.Name)}&SfdcServerURL‌​=
{!API.Partner_Server_URL_280}&SfdcSessionID={!API.Session_ID}");
```

or you can use the [javascript encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) function as well to get a proper url and redirect

Answer (score 0):

I hope URLENCODE function will solve your issue. Can you please try replacing `SfdcOpName={!Opportunity.Name}` with `SfdcOpName={!URLENCODE(Opportunity.Name)}` and try again. Thanks.